# How to get instead of trigger to be triggered

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to get this instead of trigger to work when a table is updated (and the view is updated by the trigger).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER increase_boss_sub_salary
INSTEAD of UPDATE ON emp_sub_view
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE employees
        SET salary = salary * 1.05 
        WHERE employee_id = :old.employee_id;
END;
```

emp_sub_view is a view of employee_subordinates.

employee_subordinates is triggered by this trigger which works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER keep_sub_count
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        IF DELETING OR UPDATING
            THEN
            UPDATE employee_subordinates
            SET subcount = subcount - 1
            WHERE employee_id = :old.manager_id; 
        END IF;

        IF INSERTING OR UPDATING
            THEN
            UPDATE employee_subordinates
            set subcount = subcount + 1
            WHERE employee_id = :new.manager_id;
        END IF;

END;
```

Lets pretend I update an employee to a new manager. That triggers the keep_sub_count trigger which then updates employee_subordinates and it's view emp_sub_view. Wouldn't my trigger increase_boss_sub_salary be triggered when this happens because emp_sub_view changed? I can't seem to to get it fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your increase_boss_sub_salary trigger will fire when you update the view. 
That does not mean that it fires when the underlying data is being updated. It means it fires when a update SQL statement is executed on the view.

For example.

```
update emp_sub_view
set salary=salary * 1.05
where employee_id=44;
```

With the instead of trigger you can update the data that is being presented in the view and redirect the updates to the underlying tables.

Your trigger will then be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER increase_boss_sub_salary
INSTEAD of UPDATE ON emp_sub_view
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE employees
        SET salary = :new.salary
        WHERE employee_id = :old.employee_id;
END;
```